# Oracle dialect for Oracle12c database

Tags: java, hibernate, oracle12c

So far we have been using the dialect org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9Dialect
for hibernate.dialect property for all Oracle versions (10g/11g). We plan
to use Oracle12c as well. Our initial tests indicate that continuing with
Oracle9Dialect for Oracle12c will work. Does anyone have any suggestions/
recommendations/use cases where we would need to use a different dialect for
Oracle12c while maintaining backward compatibility with earlier Oracle versions
(10g/11g) ?

It would be great if some one can point me to an existing wiki/documentation
which I might have missed on oversight.

Answer (score 0):

I was using the Oracle10gDialect, but Jboss 6.1 failed to start properly.  I had to remove Hibernate 3.6.6 and install Hibernate 4.2.15 and make a few code changes to properly support 12c.  To be clear, I think the old dialect would work, but JBoss didn't seem to like it.

Comment: Can you explain the changes you did to support Oracle 12c in Hibernate 4.2.15, please?